# Merge a list of its objects

Tags: r, merge, xts

I am new here and starting to learn R. I have some files I want to be read by R, then translated into xts and finally to merge all those files. I have already managed to have the xts files on a list, but I find it impossible to merge them. My code looks like this:

```
stock = list()
csv = dir(pattern = "*.csv") 
csvlen = length(csv)
for (k in 1:csvlen)
{
  stock[[k]] = as.xts(read.zoo(csv[k],sep=',',tz='EST',header=T,format='%m/%d/%y %H:%M'))
  stock[[k]] = exchangeHoursOnly(stock[[k]],daybegin = "15:30:00",dayend =     "22:00:00")
}
```

After the idea would be to merge the data into one xts as follows

```
a = cbind(stock[[1]],stock[[2]] (...) stock[[k]])
```

However, i couldn't find the way to merge all files without naming each one of them.

I have tried:

```
do.call(cbind, stock)
```

But this only puts one file as header of the other. Any suggestions on how to merge all the data contained in the list stock?? Thanks

Comment: Could you try `Reduce(cbind,stock)`?

Comment: Do you need to bind in columns or row-by-row?